# A more elegant way to compute within-group proportions in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Given a data_frame `df <- data_frame(X = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), Y = c('M', 'N', 'M', 'M', 'N'))`, I need to come up with a data_frame that tells us that 50% of `A`'s are `M`, 50% of `A`'s are `N`, 67% of `B`'s are `M`, and 33% of `B`'s are `N`.

I have a little routine that I use to do it, but it seems horrible.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(X = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), Y = c('M', 'N', 'M', 'M', 'N')) 
# here we go...
df %>% 
  group_by(X) %>% 
  mutate(n_X = n()) %>% 
  group_by(X, Y) %>% 
  summarise(PERCENT = n() / first(n_X))
```

which outputs,

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: X [?]

      X     Y   PERCENT
  <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
1     A     M 0.5000000
2     A     N 0.5000000
3     B     M 0.6666667
4     B     N 0.3333333
```

Is there not a better way to do this? Surely I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `prop.table`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(X, Y) %>%
  count() %>%
  mutate(PERCENT = prop.table(n))
```

The result:

```
      X     Y     n   PERCENT
  <chr> <chr> <int>     <dbl>
1     A     M     1 0.5000000
2     A     N     1 0.5000000
3     B     M     2 0.6666667
4     B     N     1 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 4):

We can try in base R using `table` and `rowSums`

```
new_df <- table(df$X, df$Y)
new_df/rowSums(new_df)

#          M         N
#  A 0.5000000 0.5000000
#  B 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this:

with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  count(X, Y) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))
```

with `base R`

```
tbl <- xtabs(~X+Y, df)
as.data.frame(tbl/rowSums(tbl), responseName = "prop")
```

with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)[, .N, by = .(X,Y)]
setDT(DT)[, prop := N/sum(N), by = 'X']
DT

#   X Y N      prop
#1: A M 1 0.5000000
#2: A N 1 0.5000000
#3: B M 2 0.6666667
#4: B N 1 0.3333333
```